# How to plot the correlation of two Cells in a scatter plot

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Okay, I love to use excel to model my complex heat convection problem in a very visual way.
But now I want to compare the result for different input values. Is there a way to create a plot where x is my input variable (in a range i can decide) and y the result (which can be found in a different cell)?

I know, normally you would need to create a table that has all x values in one column and all y values are calculated in ONE STEP in an adjacent cell. But as my calculation is quite complex, this is not the case.
So in a very simplified way, this is how my excel looks like:
[Simplified version of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVC6m.png)

How would you create a scatter plot of such a relation?

I tried to google the problem, but I didn't find a similar question

Comment: You mention multiple columns, but your sample data only has one column of numbers, unless you transposed things? Why not create a separate table with the two relevant columns and generate the chart from that?

Comment: The original table is much more complicated and the columns are not always below each other. I was imagining something like  x = range(1,10) and then it would give me the corresponding y values as output for a plot

Comment: Columns are by definition next to each other. Are you talking about rows? Have you tried creating a separate table to generate the chart? Maybe provide an example table that has more than one data point and the chart you expect to get from it